# Get only the properties of the superclass from subclass

Tags: c#, .net, inheritance

I have a class that contains some properties, and a class that inherits from that class that adds some additional properties.  Unfortunately I can only get the inherited class from a data service.  But I only need the properties on the superclass.  How can this be accomplished?

I have the following classes:

```
namespace MA.ECCA.WebServices
{
    public class Player
    {
        Public Player();

        public string fname{get; set;}
        public string lname{get; set;}
    }

    public class PlayerData : Player
    {
        public PlayerData();

        public Stats stats {get; set;}

    }
}
```

Given an object of type PlayerData how could I get an object with only the Player properties?

I have tried the following:

```
Player player = GetPlayerStats();//returns object of type PlayerStats populated with data
```

and...

```
Player player = (Player)GetPlayerStats();
```

In both cases I end up with all the data, I only want an object that contains the fname and lname...

Comment: Clarify what you mean by data service. WCF service? Something else?

Comment: Its a web service I dont know many details about it, except I make a web request to it and it gives me back a PlayerData object populated with data.

Comment: Perhaps you can explain why you want this? You have an object that has the data you want and some more on. You can use it like an object of type `Player` and entirely ignore the extra data. You could create a new Player without the extra data but I'm not sure why you would want to. Some extra context may help us get to the solution that works for you.

Comment: Since it doesnt work, I figured my attempt doesn't make sense.  The reason behind my question is to understand why...

Comment: @Chris For one I only need the information in player.  This information is being sent via an ajax call and there can be a lot of data.  Wouldn't it be better to send less?

Comment: In order for you to send less data via the ajax call, you would need to change the web service. Can you modify the web service?

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov I mean from my code I have to get the information as is from the web service, I can't do anything about that.  But when my library gets a call it won't be passing along useless information.

Comment: In this specific case it might almost be better to have a specific Data Transfer Object that is tailored for your exact purposes. It means that if you later on decide you need more or even less data to be transferred via AJAX that you have good control without having to mess around with your core data objects. Otherwise MArtin Mulder's answers at http://stackoverflow.com/a/26549512/338068 is a good way to go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I understand correctly, the method `GetPlayerStats` always returns an object of type `PlayerData`. And I understand this cannot be changed and you want to receive less data (no statistics, only the first and last name).

The object of a certain type always stay the same; it will always maintain the same members. It will not suddenly get smaller. Casting it up to a `Player` or even an `object` will make some/all properties less visibility, but they are still inside that object.

In your case you should create a totally new instance of type `Player` and copy the data from the first object to the new one. For example:

```
public class Player
{
    public Player();
    public Player(Player original)
    {
        fname = original.fname;
        lname = original.lname;
    }

    public string fname{get; set;}
    public string lname{get; set;}
}
...
PlayerData playerData = GetPlayerStats();
Player player = new Player(playerData);
```

If you do this often, you might consider creating a generic method and use reflection to copy properties from the first object to the next.